# How to add CSS via custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am making my first plugin. I create a folder in `\wp-content\plugins`, create a test.css and a test.php file.

Here is my test.css:

```
body {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Here is my test.php (Taken from [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#combining-enqueue-functions)):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for Quảcầu.com
Description: Site specific code changes for Quảcầu.com
*/

function add_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'test.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

But the color doesn't change. Do you know why? Of course I have activated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```php
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'test.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
```

Neither of those files are in your theme. `get_stylesheet_uri` refers to the `style.css` that has the themes name etc, and `get_template_directory_uri` is the URL of the parent theme. Neither of those are your plugin folder.

*You can confirm this by looking at the browser dev tools and seeing an error in the console that it tried to load a `test.css` from your themes folder and failed.*

Instead use `plugins_url`.

e.g.

```
plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png', __FILE__ )
```

Where the first parameter is the path to the file in your plugin folder, and the second parameter is the main plugin file location on the server.

So this:

```php
get_template_directory_uri() . 'test.css'
```

becomes:

```php
plugins_url( 'test.css', __FILE__ );
```

Comment: Follow up question: [The CSS file in the plugin changes, but the outcome doesn't change. Why is that?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/384729/64282)

Comment: Browser cache, it's a caching thing. Clear all caches. If it didn't work, it's because you did not clear all caches successfully